# Mock a method within a model method in CakePHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

I am running **CakePHP 2.8.X**, and am trying to write a unit test for a Model function.

Let's call the model `Item`, and I'm trying to test its `getStatus` method.

However, that model makes a call to its `find` within the `getStatus` method.

So something like this:

```php
class Item extends Model
{
    public function getStatus($id) {
      // Calls our `$this->Item-find` method
      $item = $this->find('first', [
        'fields' => ['status'],
        'conditions' => ['Item.id' => $id]
      ]);

      $status = $item['status'];

      $new_status = null;

      // Some logic below sets `$new_status` based on `$status`
      // ...

      return $new_status;
    }
}
```

The logic to set "`$new_status`" is a bit complex, which is why I want to write some tests for it.

However, I'm not entirely sure how to override the `find` call within `Item::getStatus`.

Normally when I want to mock a Model's function, I use [`$this->getMock`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.SubjectTest.php) coupled with `method('find')->will($this->returnValue($val_here))`, but I don't want to completely mock my `Item` since I want to test its actual `getStatus` function.

That is, in my test function, I'm going to be calling:

```php
// This doesn't work since `$this->Item->getStatus` calls out to
// `$this->Item->find`, which my test suite doesn't know how to compute.
$returned_status = $this->Item->getStatus($id);
$this->assertEquals($expected_status, $returned_status);
```

So how do I communicate to my real `Item` model within my test that it should override its internal call to its `find` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew this had to be an issue others have faced, and it turns out PHPUnit has a very easy way to address this!

[This tutorial](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-5-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/) essentially gave me the answer.

I do need to create a mock, but by only passing in `'find'` as the methods I'd like to mock, PHPUnit helpfully leaves all other methods in my Model alone and **does not** override them.

The relevant part from the above tutorial is:

> Passing an array of method names to your `getMock` second argument produces a mock object where the methods you have identified
>
> - Are all stubs,
> - All return null by default,
> - Are easily overridable
>
> Whereas methods you did not identify
>
> - Are all mocks,
> - **Run the actual code contained within the method when called** (*emphasis mine*),
> - Do not allow you to override the return value

Meaning, I can take that mocked model, and call my `getStatus` method *directly from it*. That method will run its real code, and when it gets to `find()`, it'll just return whatever I passed into `$this->returnValue`.

I use a [`dataProvider`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers.examples.DataTest.php) to pass in what I want the find method to return, as well as the result to test against in my `assertEquals` call.

So my test function looks something like:

```php
/**
 * @dataProvider provideGetItemStatus
 */
public function testGetItemStatus($item, $status_to_test) {
    // Only mock the `find` method, leave all other methods as is
    $item_model = $this->getMock('Item', ['find']);

    // Override our `find` method (should only be called once)
    $item_model
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('find')
        ->will($this->returnValue($item));

    // Call `getStatus` from our mocked model.
    // 
    // The key part here is I am only mocking the `find` method,
    // so when I call `$item_model->getStatus` it is actually
    // going to run the real `getStatus` code. The only method
    // that will return an overridden value is `find`.
    // 
    // NOTE: the param for `getStatus` doesn't matter since I only use it in my `find` call, which I'm overriding
    $result = $item_model->getStatus('dummy_id');

    $this->assertEquals($status_to_test, $result);
}

public function provideGetItemStatus() {
    return [
        [
            // $item
            ['Item' => ['id' = 1, 'status' => 1, /* etc. */]],

            // status_to_test
            1
        ],

        // etc...
    ];
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer so others know you've solved your problem. Well done, this will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

one way to mock find could be to use a test specific subclass.

You could create a TestItem that extends item and overrides find so it doesn't perform a db call.

Another way could be to encapsulate the new_status logic and unittests it independent of the model